# Google Drive - Import to Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, importrange

I'm looking for a script or formula to help with an issue I'm having.

I'm trying to import a certain range, or tab, from the most recent spreadsheet (or one with a particular name format) from a shared Google Drive to one, centralized, spreadsheet.

I'd need this to update daily.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Cool. What have you tried?

Comment: @Perplexabot - Really nothing, yet. I'm not sure of any way to reference a folder in Google Sheets, which is the main problem I'm trying to solve for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try simple `IMPORTRANGE` like:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet-ID-or-URL"; "Sheet-name!A1:D20")
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried something like that. However, a new spreadsheet is created daily that I would need to reference. That's why I was hoping I could 'scrape' the folder in Google Drive for the most recent spreadsheet, to import that?